# How do I correctly cache a themed menu output?

Tags: 8, caching, theming

In `mytheme_preprocess_menu()`, I am altering the main menu:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ('menu__main' == $hook) {
    if ($node) {
      _mytheme_menu_replace_with_project_items($node, $variables['items']);
    }
  }
}
```

In `_mytheme_menu_replace_with_project_items()`, I check whether the current node is a project node, and show that node's submenu instead.

When I visit the node the menu gets displayed, but when I add another node with another project reference, the menu of the former node gets displayed.

How can I correctly cache that?

I tried with the following code, but it didn't work.

```
$variables['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node:' . $node->id();
$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'route.name';
$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'theme';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this combination worked...

```
$variables['#cache']['tags'] = ['node:' . $node->id()];
$variables['#cache']['contexts'] = ['route', 'theme'];
$variables['#cache']['keys'] = ['entity_view', 'node', $node->id()];
```

I dont see a huge difference to my first attempt but whatever!

Comment: `$variables['#cache']` should not even be used, since `$variables` is not a render array.

Comment: `$variables['#cache']['contexts]` existed in the first place, i was just adding contexts and tags

Comment: @Alex: It is the context `route` what makes the difference. `route.name` is without parameters and is the same for all nodes.